# Trying to reload Image variable until successful or a max amount of attempts is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, recursion, reload

I am trying to create a function that will recursively try to reload an image until it either is successful, or a maximum amount of attempts is reached. I have created this function, but it doesn't work (is it due to the fact that the reference to the image has changed?):

```
function reload (image, URL, maxAttempts)
{
image.onerror = image.onabort = null;

  if (maxAttempts > 0)
  {
    var newImg = new Image ();
    newImg.src = URL;
    newImg.onerror = image.onabort = reload (image, URL, maxAttempts - 1);
    newImg.onload = function () {
      newImg.onerror = newImg.onabort = null;
      image = newImg;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    alert ("Error loading image " + URL); /* DEBUG */
  }
}
```

Which is used in the following manner:

`var globalTestImage = new Image ();`
`reload (globalTestImage, "testIMG.jpg", 4);`

Rather than it attempting to load "testIMG.jpg" four times, and waiting in between attempts, it instead tries to load it twice, and regardless of whether it was successful the second time around it will display the error message.

What am I doing there? More precisely, why is it acting the way it is, rather than retrying to load the image 4 times?

Comment: `newImg.onerror = image.onabort = reload (image, URL, maxAttempts - 1);` – you are not assigning a function _reference_ as event handler here, but you are _calling_ the function (so only its return value will be assigned as the event handler.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solve this issue in a simple (if inelegant) way:

```
    try
    {
      canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage (testImage, 0, 0);
      backgroundLoaded = true;
    }
    catch (err)
    {
      testImage = new Image ();
      testImage.src = "placeholder.jpg";
    }
```

The idea is that if an image failed to load, it will fail when rendering it on the canvas, producing an error. When such an error happens, we can create a new image and try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($) {
    var retries = 5; //<--retries
    $( document).ready(function(){
        $('img').one('error', function() {
            var $image = $(this);
            $image.attr('alt', 'Still didn\'t load');
            if (typeof $image !== 'undefined') {
                if (typeof $image.attr('src') !== 'undefined') {
                    $image.attr('src', retryToLoadImage($image));
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function retryToLoadImage($img) {
        var $newImg = $('<img>');
        var $src = ($img.attr('src')) || '';
        $newImg.attr('src', $src);
        $newImg.one('error', function() {
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                if (retries > 0) {
                    retries--;
                    retryToLoadImage($newImg);
                }
            }, 1000); //<-retry interval
        });

        $newImg.one('load', function() {
            return $newImg.attr('src');
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Some code I wrote for the same case a while ago. Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank @CBroe, had to edit out the company name in the String

Comment: the above script is for HTML image elements, right?

Comment: @MKII I will make it more general